# Move javascript to tag div id

Tags: javascript

I'm playing javascript embeded, which code javascript I get from my server, the code javascript will generate banner.

Example javascript from my server is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    <!--//<![CDATA[
    var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://203.130.226.231/advediax/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://203.130.226.231/advediax/www/delivery/ajs.php');
    var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
    if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
    document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
    document.write ("?zoneid=1");
    document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
    if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
    document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
    document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
    if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
    if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
    if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
    document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
    //]]>-->
</script>
```

And in below there are tag div id banner.

```
<div id="banner">For banner</div>

<script>
// Possible to move script from my server into tag banner?
// If yes, how to do it?
</script>
```

The condition html now approximately such as below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            <!--//<![CDATA[
            var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://203.130.226.231/advediax/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://203.130.226.231/advediax/www/delivery/ajs.php');
            var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
            if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
            document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
            document.write ("?zoneid=1");
            document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
            if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
            document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
            document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
            if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
            if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
            if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
            document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
            //]]>-->
        </script>
        <div id="banner"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I want to such as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner">
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            <!--//<![CDATA[
            var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://203.130.226.231/advediax/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://203.130.226.231/advediax/www/delivery/ajs.php');
            var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
            if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
            document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
            document.write ("?zoneid=1");
            document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
            if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
            document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
            document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
            if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
            if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
            if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
            document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
            //]]>-->
        </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the problem I cannot insert and paste my script to div id banner, because the content owned by other. So I just owned to mainpulation javascript.
My question, possible to move javascript from my server into tag div id banner?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('banner').innerHTML = 'script string (including tags)';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I cannot insert 'script string (including tags)', My script from my server will there in above and has been loaded. I must be get the string from regex example.

Comment: change the "JavaScript from the server" snippet to look for the '#banner' element and insert the script ...

Comment: Is there any other way? I had change my post in order to know my condition.

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery it might be possible to use:

```
jQuery.getElementByID("banner").text(*Insert your code here*);
```